# Does Pentaho Data Interation aka Kettle 6.0 support failover clustering?

Tags: java, tomcat, pentaho, kettle, pdi

Can the Pentaho Data Integration server (community edition) support any type of Failover via active/passive or active/active clustering?

We are new to Pentaho and want to use it for importing inbound ETL files in continuous production environment. Everything in the documentation talks about MASTER/SLAVE/SLAVE configuration for throughput but throughput is not our issue - just failover.

If our ONE tomcat MASTER DI server goes down, how do we keep processing jobs?

How can a separate server takeover the role of polling for files and importing the data?

We are processing files once an hour or once a day probably from Chron jobs launching Kettle.

Can we have two different MASTER DI servers pointing at the same DB? Can they use the same

Is there a different way?